# Proving the convergence of a given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $z_1>0, a>0.$ $z(n+1)=$$\sqrt{a+z(n)}$ . How do we prove that $z(n)$ is convergent?

Comment: You mean $z_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+z_n}$ I guess, right?

Comment: One criterion for convergence is that the sequence is bounded and monotone. Does $z_n$ meet these criteria?

Comment: yes i mean that only, i want help on how to check for the boundedness and monotonicity of that sequence..!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There is only one positive root of $z=\sqrt{a+z},$ call it $c$. Then depending on whether $z_1$ is to the right or left of $c$ the iteration will converge monotone decreasing or increasing to $c$. To finish, get the expression for $c$ and show (for the case $z_1>c$) that from $z>c$ it follows that $z>\sqrt{a+z}>c$ also. In fact the first inequality is simple from looking at the fact that $z>c$, and the second follows on squaring both sides. Proceed similarly in the other case where $0< z_1<c$. Of course if $z_1=c$ it's a constant sequence. You'll also have to use that a bounded monotone sequence has a limit, and that such a limit if it exists must be a root of $z=\sqrt{a+z}.$